# iOS: UITableViewController - when to refresh (design)?

Tags: ios, notifications, refresh, uitableview, push

I have a UITableViewController that displays a list of messages. I use CoreData and NSFetchedResultsController to cash/store each object corresponding to a cell. I wonder when to refresh the table to be in sync with the server. On the one hand, I could go for manual refresh only, but I want the table view to be in sync automatically. On the other hand, I could refresh every time the table view appears, but that seems wasteful. 
What is the normal approach in this case? Use Push Notifications and refresh every time a push is received? But what if the user disables push notifications?

Answer (score 0):

I assume when you say "the server", you're talking about some remote server on the Internet. In that case, if there are frequent updates on the server that the user will need/want, it's not unreasonable to refresh when the tableview appears (or more accurately, inquire with the server to see if a refresh is needed and only download updates rather than redownloading everything, and only refresh if there's new data ... that kind of depends upon the nature of your server). If you do this sort of logic, you'll want to do it asynchronously, though, so the user experience isn't delayed while you check for updates in the background. But if there's a good chance that the user will need/want updated data, save them the effort of tapping on a refresh button. Think of the mail program: You want to see your existing emails, but you probably want the program to check for email every time you pull up the "list of emails" tableview.

If server updates are infrequent and/or if your server protocol is a little slow, you can probably put in some hybrid of "refresh when the tableview appears only if the last refresh was longer than x minutes ago". If you do this sort of conditional check for data refresh, you'll probably then have to provide a UI to allow the user to manually refresh, see when the last refresh took place, etc. Think of a corporate news feed where there are unlikely to be a ton of minute-by-minute updates, but rather daily or weekly updates.

Also, implied by some of my earlier comments, you may want to make sure you're doing server updates in the background, and possibly proactively, too. (e.g. you might want to initiate checks for updates server data in the background as soon as the app is fired up, reducing the latency when the user goes to the particular tableview). Or you might trigger asynchronous checks for updates while the user is still on the tableview in question (e.g. you're looking at scoring summary for a sporting event in progress). It all depends upon the nature of the changes of server data, the sort of server interfaces you have access to, and the user's expectations. Regardless, never block the user interface with annoying spinners or the like if you can prevent it.

So, unfortunately there is no simple answer to your question, as the answer is contingent upon, at a minimum, (a) how quickly the server can respond to inquiries regarding the existence of data updates and, subsequently, download those updates; (b) how frequently the server data changes; and (c) how likely is the user looking for updated data (don't have a UX where the user feels compelled to have to tap on a refresh button all the time).